# Dielectric Slab: Force due to fringing field

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields, capacitance, dielectric

A parallel plate capacitor whose plates are maintained at a constant potential difference has a partially inserted dielectric slab. The force on the dielectric slab is given in most of the books. (This is in fact quite a popular problem so I assume you all already know about the expression).

However, in my textbook (and many others) they simply use the formula for the capacitance which is derived by *assuming no fringing effect of field* to explain a phenomenon that mainly arises due to fringing effect! This seems particularly strange to me.

I therefore have doubts whether that expression for force on dielectric slab is *really* correct or not.

Moreover, how do i go about finding the 'more correct' expression for force on dielectric which doesn't (of course) assume uniform electric field?

Comment: The force on a partially inserted dielectric in a capacitor is generally found using the method of "virtual work". We just differentiate the energy stored with respect to the length of the dielectric inserted. And the energy stored in a capacitor accounts for the fringing of the electric field lines. This method is just an indirect way to sidestep the calculation of the complex interactions of fringing field lines with the dielectric. What do you think is wrong with this approach?

Comment: In the approach they put the value of capacitance of the  parallel plate which is assumed by assuming uniform electric field between plates. ( C = A*€/d ) They then use this value to find energy stored in the combination (1/2 * C * V^2)

Comment: I don't think that they should put this value of C. The value of C obtained by assuming uniform field would obviously give the incorrect value of change in stored energy of the system as well as the work done by the battery